# subtotal detail payroll lines by employee id

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I have a query that looks like:

```
select e.employed, 
       p.Paycode, 
       p.MTDHours_1, 
       p.MTDHours_2, 
       p.MTDHours_3, 
       p.MTDHours_4, 
       p.MTDHours_5, 
      (p.MTDHours_1 + p.MTDHours_2 + 
       p.MTDHours_3 +  p.MTDHours_4 + 
       p.MTDHours_5) as 'Total Hours'
  from employee as e, 
       payroll as p
```

The MTDHours field is an array with a number of hours for each month, so total Hours is the summation of the 5-month period.

For each employee, the results will be one line for each pay code, with a total at the end of the row.
I need to sum the rows based on the employed, to get just a total of hours worked by each employee for the 5-months. 
I haven't found a way to do that. If anyone has a suggestion, please let me know.
Thank you.

Comment: *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "_SQL_" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.